# Consume Google Elevations Api from Android

Tags: android, json, retrofit, elevation

I want to get the json file containing the elevation of a given latitude and longitude (and also providing the api key). I have been reading a lot and find out that Retrofit is the best option in Android, but I don't know how to specify the params.

```
public interface ServiceApi {
//url format
//"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/elevation/json?locations="
// latitude+","+longitude+"&key="+key;
@GET("")
public void getJSON(Callback<List<JsonElevation>> jsonElevationCallback);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an Elevations API key to test this with but using Retrofit's [documentation](http://square.github.io/retrofit/), something like this should work.

```
    @GET("/maps/api/elevation/json")
    public Call<List<JsonElevation>> getJSON(@Query("locations") String latAndLng,
                                                 @Query("key") String key);
```

Then to call it:

```
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://maps.googleapis.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()))
        .build();

    ServiceApi serviceApi = retrofit.create(ServiceApi.class);

    String latAndLng = String.format("%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
    Call<List<JsonElevation>> elevations = serviceApi.getJSON(latAndLng, key);

    elevations.enqueue();  // for asychronous response          
    //or        
    elevations.execute();   // for synchronous response
```